# How to log in with another account?

Tags: support, login, android-app

I am using the stack exchange Android app and signed with my account named "kangkan". I just tried to log in with my friend's account. So I logged out from "settings".

But when I tried to sign in with the other account then google smart lock only led me to the previous account. I tried turning off the smart lock in google settings. But It is not working.

Is there anyone here is using android stack exchange app and have solution to this issue. Please help?

Comment: When you logged into your own account "kangkan" did you click *Save Password*? It might have automatically logged you into your own account, but I could be wrong, but you see, I have been on the mathematics stack exchange (MSE) for a while, so when I type *m* in the search bar, it automatically highlights *math.stackexchange* so I just go from there and it automatically takes me to my account without my logging in

Comment: While I use the Android SE app quite a bit, my login is integrated with Google as an OpenID provider.  It's not clear from what you told us whether you or your friend use a StackExchange password on these accounts or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. What I did to solve it is to turn off  Google smartlock on my android Phone and start the app over.